# set common custom error pages for main domain and all subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

how can one set a common set of custom error pages like 403, 404 etc for all subdomains as well as the main www domain.

i have many subdomains so i do not want to make redundant copies of my error pages placed in root of subdomains. i just want to have single html file for each error and serve it for entire website.

giving absolute path in htaccess like

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.org/404.html
```

works but cause a redirect and the url changes. the url should not change and error must be displayed on the same url itself.

setting relative link

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

works for the main domain but will not work for subdomains as they have a separate root.

i have a lot of subdomains so dont want to maintain error pages for all subdomains separately and putting error pages inside root of each subdomain doesnt seem to be a good option.

any approach or methods you can suggest will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because subdomains have separate roots, they cannot access error pages using relative paths, i.e. by going up in directory.

Possible solution for common error page for entire website like this will be to use absolute path for error pages, but this will execute a redirect and the URL in address bar will change.

Or what you can do it, use a back-end solution like PHP or Django to deliver consistent error pages for all subdomains.

Comment: how is this answering anything asked in question?

Answer (score 0):

The best work around I have found around this problem is to make use of the symlinks or symbolic-link for a folder containing error pages for your entire website.

> Create a directory named `error` in the "Root-Directory" of your
>   **Parent-Domain (parent.com)**

containing all your error pages 400.html,401.html,403.html etc.

> Add `symlinks` to the directory named the `error` in the
>   "Root-Directory" of your **sub-domains (sub1.parent.com,
>   sub2.parent.com, etc)** as follow through console:

```
$ cd /var/www/html/sub1
$ ln -s ../error
$ cd /var/www/html/sub2
$ ln -s ../error
```

> Then have the following lines in all the .htacess files

```
#Custom Error Pages
ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
```

And enjoy consistent custom error pages everywhere...!!
Hope this helps :D